# changing ASCII characters -invalid type?

Tags: c, xcode, ascii, type-conversion

I need to systematically transform ASCII characters (e.g.,  change 'a' to 't') that I pass from one string to another.  This compiles but when run it crashes (bad access).  Can someone give me a pointer?

```
char  **string1,  string2[40] = "\0";

(*string1)[0] = string2[0] + 25; [BAD ACCESS]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a pointer, but it isn't pointing anywhere.

If you want to copy from `string2` to `string1`, you have to allocate space for that string as well.

Perhaps

```
char string1[40], string2[40];
```